# Errors Messages, keep showing InValid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails CREATE controller for a model, if the name of the record already exists, via JS I'm outputting the following response:

```
<%=@space.errors%>
```

Which outputs:

> permissionsis invalidnameThis project name is already in use

In the model I have:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name :message => 'This project name is already in use'
```

How do I get rid of the noise: "permissionsis invalidname" for the life of me I can't find it in the docs? Apologies if I'm missing something hugely obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are actually returning the array containing all the error objects.

What you actually want is:

```
<ul>
<% @space.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%=h msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This will give you a list of the errors.

I'm also pretty sure there's a nicer way to do this (i.e. some sort of helper built in to rails), but I haven't been able to find it in the docs for rails 3.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work... Still says "Permissions is invalidName This project name is already in use"